# Using Google Cloud or Drive to Programatically Convert Word to PDF

Tags: pdf, ms-word, google-drive-api, google-oauth

Candidates use my PHP application to upload their CV in either Word or PDF format.  I want to convert the Word documents (doc or docx) to PDF.  I have tried using on-server solutions (PHP libraries), but can not find one that is reliable enough so I am now exploring Google solutions.

It seems that the Drive API has just what I need.  I can:

- upload a Word document and request conversion to Google Doc.
- export the doc as a PDF
- delete the doc

The problem is that (as far as I can see), the only way I can access the Drive API is via OAuth 2, which is quite an overhead in the case of simple server-to-server access.  I would prefer to use a simple API key.

As far as I can see, if I want to use an API key, then I need to sign up for a Google Service Account, which again seems like quite an overhead.  (I only want to convert some files, right?).

Is there a straightforward way to achieve my goal (using Google resources)?  Or are the two options above my only choices?

Comment: You want to achieve to convert from word formato to PDF without OAuth2 and Service Account. If my understanding is correct, how about using [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) with Google Apps Script? In this case, you can achieve it without OAuth2 and Service Account. If this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use case is a perfect fit for a Service Account. It's not really much of an overhead, say 10 minutes to set up the account and a couple of hours to write the auth code. If you would rather use a regular account, check out [How do I authorise an app (web or installed) without user intervention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention?answertab=active#tab-top) which has step by step instructions and sample code.